# Terminal-Only Capable Voip

Tags: raspbian, terminal

I am trying to run mumble on my headless pi. Unfortunately, mumble wants an x server to run. Is there any way to get a client to run through only terminal?

I cannot seem to find anything quick and simple. Teamspeak apparently refuses to write a version for the pi. I have found asterisk and elastix, but both are enormous, and i think asterisk is a full OS.

If not, are there other simple/small voip client/server programs that work on the pi in bash? My final goal is to have my pi as both the server and a client that can talk to other people.

Comment: Asterisk in an Exchange. It does not allow you to make calls instead it manages phone calls and routes them to the correct place, like phone line, VoiP server or other VoiP client using your Asterisk server. You need a VoiP client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`linphone` is quite small (~25MiB with gtk dependencies IIRC); Try `apt-get install linphone-nogtk`